# Simple HTML Dom Parser - Can't put all href links into the same array after scraping them

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape a website with 2 or 3 href links for downloading pdfs. 
this is the format of the webpage

```
<p class="file">
                        <a class="ext-pdf" rel="file" href="http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2573&amp;dl=1">Deadbolts Catalogue Section</a>
                        <span class="bdi">(.pdf, 660 kB)</span>
                    </p>



                    <p class="file">
                        <a class="ext-pdf" rel="file" href="http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2625&amp;dl=1">Lockwood Home Security Solutions</a>
                        <span class="bdi">(.pdf, 3.7 MB)</span>
                    </p>



                    <p class="file">
                        <a class="ext-pdf" rel="file" href="http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=3045&amp;dl=1">Lockwood Elements Brochure</a>
                        <span class="bdi">(.pdf, 1.2 MB)</span>
                    </p>
```

So far I can get the links from the DOM but I cannot put them into the same array.
This is my code:

```
foreach ($html->find('a.[class="ext-pdf"]') as $pdfurl) {
   $testarray=array($pdfurl->href);   


    print_r($testarray);

}
```

And this is the output
    Array ( [0] => http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2594&dl=1
 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2625&dl=1 )

what am I doing wrong?
thanks! :)

**Here is the solution for anyone wondering:**

```
foreach ($html->find('a.[class="ext-pdf"]') as $pdfurl) 
$testarray[] = $pdfurl->href."<br>";
{



    print_r($testarray);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$testarray[] = $pdfurl->href;
```

is what you should have. You're simply assining an array containing a url to the SAME variable each time, so each loop iteration trashes the variable you set last time around.

Comment: Thanks,that has put me on the right track.
    foreach ($html->find('a.[class="ext-pdf"]') as $pdfurl) {
     
  $testarray[] = $pdfurl->href."<br>";
  
  print_r($testarray);
 
 }
Gives me this output:
    Array ( [0] => http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2594&dl=1
) Array ( [0] => http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2594&dl=1
[1] => http://static-mpc.assaabloy.com/lockwoodfile/Fetchfile.aspx?id=2625&dl=1
)

I'm still a bit confused but I think it's counting the number of items in the loop and creating an array for each one?

Comment: no. it's creating one array and adding the links as elements in that array.